# How to integrate credit card payment into my application?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, credit-card

I have an online category, and I would like to let the user pay the bill, how can I accept credit card for the user? What kind of things I need to do? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take payments directly then you need to establish an online merchant bank account with your bank, and then integrate with their preferred provider, such as SecPay or WorldPay.  If you don't want to set up that account, or can't because you don't have trading history, then you are better off integrating with PayPal.  All payment providers take a commission on sales, PayPal is generally cheaper than a formal bank route until you hit a pretty large threshold, in the UK it's about £70,000. You can take credit card payments via PayPal, you aren't restricted to using PayPal credit only

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a provider, SecPay, Paypal, Worldpay all have API's that you can use to handle card payments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a payment processing service which will handle the payment for you and will transfer funds. PayPal is one of the most obvious provider. Check their website (click on the Business tab, I can't get a link because it redirects me to the Italian version). You will need a business account, then you will receive tokens and the instructions to integrate the payment in your checkout process.